# How to deal with garbage characters in a string?

Tags: c++, string, c++17

Suppose I have a string that contains a necessary numeric character but it is not terminated by '/0', it has garbage characters instead. Actually, the string has garbage characters after the number. So how to deal with the garbage character while storing that numerical character in another string or variable?

Comment: How do you define "garbage character"? Does the string have a length (such that you know that anything past the end of that length is invalid)?

Comment: Once you violate the rules of the language and have UB your program is considered broken and anything can happen. Also a "garbage character" could be anything including valid looking data.

Comment: AFAIK all compilers are adding implementing `std::string` in such way that it always have terminating zero at the end (standard do not enforces that, `c_str()` have to return null terminated buffer). So please provide [mcve] showing your problem.

Comment: @MarekR: `std::string` has been null-terminated (albeit perhaps also containing nulls, of course) since C++11.

Comment: @MarekR I assume Gaurav either meant he may not have a null character after the numeric part of the string content, or he may mean "string" in the general "bunch of text in memory", rather than `std::string` sense.

Comment: What are you hoping will happen if the first "garbage" character just happens to be another digit?

Answer (score 1):

If the text be converted is in a `std::string`, then you can extract a number from the front as follows:

```
#include <sstream>
...

std::string input = "128734garbage";
std::istringstream iss{input};
int num;
if (iss >> num)
    ...use_num...
else
    std::cerr << "wasn't able to parse an int from input\n";
```

Just change `int` to `double`, `uint64_t`, ... - whatever suits your data.

If you have only a pointer to the text and know it's not null-terminated, just getting the text into a `std::string` is problematic.  You could instead use a function that converts text to a number, but stops at the first invalid character.  [`std::stol` et al](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), and the other unsigned and floating point variants linked from the same reference page, are good candidates for that.

From your "another string or variable" - the above addresses storing into a numeric variable.  You can then create a new `std::string` from the number using [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), or a `std::ostringstream`, if that's what you want to do.  This will standardise the output format though, so input like say "1E4" might end up looking like say `1000.0`.  Alternatively, with the `stol`-type functions you can use the pointer-to-the-end-of-the-number to work out the length of the numeric part, and use [`std::string::substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to extract the leading number as a new `std::string` object.

You should also be aware that the distinction between number and garbage is not always what you might expect.  For example "0XBEFHJQ" might be split by some of the above functions as 0xBEF hex and HJQ garbage.

Answer (score 1):

> So how to deal with the garbage character while storing that numerical character in another string or variable?

Only copy a substring. Example:

```
std::string example "garbage1garbage";
char numerical = example[7];
```

We got the numerical character excluding the garbage entirely.